# Eslint : no-restricted-syntax for specific require function calls

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, eslint

Current platform which we are using just moved from proprietary ECMAScript based language to Javascript.

In the proprietary language there was Arraylist class which we could use apart from native JS array. As now we have completely moved to native JS I would like to generate a ESLINT warning whenever someone tried to use Arraylist.

I read about "no-restricted-syntax" rule in Eslint and tried creating a rule for the calls like below in my code

```
require( 'dw/util/ArrayList' )
```

I came up with below syntax but this doesn't work. I even tried `arguments[0].value` instead of `arguments.value`

```
"no-restricted-syntax": [
    "warn",
    {
        "selector": "CallExpression[callee.name='require'][arguments.value='dw/util/ArrayList']",
        "message": "Please use native JS Array"
    }
]
```

I used [ESLint Parser Demo](http://eslint.org/parser/) to check the syntax tree which looks like below

```
    {
  "type": "Program",
  "start": 0,
  "end": 30,
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "ExpressionStatement",
      "start": 0,
      "end": 30,
      "expression": {
        "type": "CallExpression",
        "start": 0,
        "end": 30,
        "callee": {
          "type": "Identifier",
          "start": 0,
          "end": 7,
          "name": "require"
        },
        "arguments": [
          {
            "type": "Literal",
            "start": 9,
            "end": 28,
            "value": "dw/util/ArrayList",
            "raw": "'dw/util/ArrayList'"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "sourceType": "module"
}
```

Can someone help me with the correct syntax.

Comment: Initially I see `argument.value` should be `arguments.value`

Comment: I tried `arguments[0].value`, which I expected to work but got an eslint error.

Comment: Have you tried just `arguments[0]`?

Comment: I tried that an got a syntax error, `arguments` and `arguments.length` do not syntax error though, and highlight a warning on `require`.

Comment: @Xotic750 : It was a typo. I tried using `arguments` only & it didn't worked as expected. `arguments.length` works perfectly fine and it is mentioned in official documentation as well http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-restricted-syntax

Comment: Yeah, from my understanding it should be like CSS `X[a][b]`, my guess is that it's a bug. It would be worth logging an issue I think, if there is not one alread open for it. https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax shall be:

```
[arguments.0.value='dw/util/ArrayList']
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me,

[image]

```json
"no-restricted-syntax": [
  "warn",          
  {
    "selector": "Literal[value='dw/util/ArrayList']",
    "message": "Please use native JS Array"
  }
],
```